# catch exception via dbms_scheduler

Tags: oracle, dbms-scheduler

I am new to PL/SQL.I am running a stored_procedure using dbms_scheduler.create_job, is there anyway I can catch the exception thrown by stored procedure

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at view `ALL_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS`, column `ADDITIONAL_INFO`, see [ALL_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2048.htm#REFRN20386)

Comment: Hi, the additional info is null. do I have to set any additional attributes while scheduling the job to catch the exception?

Comment: No, should be visible anyway. What happens when you run the procedure manually? Did you check [DBMS_SCHEDULER](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_sched.htm#ARPLS72235)?